# Import current module by name in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

Is it possible for a module to import "itself" by its own name in typescript?

For instance, lets say there is a module `my-module` with a bunch of test.
Is there a chance to import it inside the tests using `import ... from "my-module"` instead of using local path (e.g. `import ... from "./my-module"`)?

As I know it can be done using the `require`, but it seems that `import` does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TypeScript tsconfig paths option e.g.

```
{
  "paths": {
      "module": ["src/path/to/module"]
    }
}
```

## More

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html